# I have a problem, this code works and connects into atlas cloud. But when i try to run it on heroku , it gets stuck. if its not properly structured?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error code below is from heroku log

```
process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/compose host=shielded-inlet-10428.herokuapp.com  fwd="66.81.177.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I managed to get this work and connect to cloud and add data to cloud from
localhost, so i didn't touch it. As i am new in this i was sure i'd break it.
But when i connect it to Heroku and try to add data into cloud and
wait a while... it gives me heroku error page.
The way i read the response data maybe it should be done differently? i was trying to follow atlas docs...

( I do have "start": "node app.js" script in my package.json.
also i had procfile but the same happened.)

maybe someone sees right away how wrong my code is and could tell me.

or if not then the problem might be bigger and i have no skills to repaire this. Yet! but to be able to create cloud based app would be really nice. I really hope theres just some easy fix problem in code.

```
// app.js

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var _ = require("lodash");

var posts = [];
const homeStartingContent="hello welcome..."
const app = express();
var axios = require("axios");
var data = JSON.stringify({
  collection: "events",
  database: "test",
  dataSource: "ekaBase",
  projection: {
    title: 1,
    content: 1,
  },
});

var config = {
  method: "post",
  url: "xxx",

  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
    "api-key":
      "xxx",
  },
  data: data,
};

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    var x = response.data.documents;
    x.forEach((element) => {
      var cloudData = {
        title: element.title,
        content: element.content,
      };
    
      posts.push(cloudData);
    });
    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
   
    console.log(error);
  });

mongoose.connect(uri);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
});

var eventData = mongoose.model("Event", eventSchema);

//Load index page using endpoint
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.render("home", {
    startingContent: homeStartingContent,
    posts,
    
  });
});


app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home", { startingContent: homeStartingContent, posts });
});

/// compose page for admin
app.get("/compose", function (req, res) {
  res.render("compose");
});


app.post("/compose", function (req, res) {
  const post = {
    title: req.body.inputTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody,
  };
  posts.push(post);

  new eventData(post)
    .save()
    .then((result) => {

      return res.send(result);     })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400);
    });
  return res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/posts/:test", function (req, res) {
  const test = _.lowerCase(req.params.test);

  posts.forEach((i) => {
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(i.title);

    if (storedTitle === test) {
      res.render("post", {
        title: i.title,
        content: i.content,
      });
    }
  });
});


let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server started successfully");
});
```

```
// home.ejs

<%- include('./partials/header.ejs') %>
<div class="container">
<p><%= startingContent%></p>

     
<% posts.forEach(function(element){ %>
     <h2><%= element.title    %></h2>
     <p> <%= element.content.substring(0,100)+" ..."%> <a href="/posts/<%=element.title %>">More</a>
</p>
<%});%>
<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
</div>
</div>
```

```
//compose.ejs 

<%- include('./partials/header.ejs') %>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Compose</h1>
<div class="form-group">
<form action="/compose" method="post">
  <label for="">Title</label>
  <input class="form-control"type="text" name="inputTitle" />
  <label for="">Post</label>
  <textarea class="form-control"name="postBody" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>

</div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit ">Publish</button></form>
<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
The problem was solved adjusting mongo Atlas network access settings.
Thanks and sorry for the question that was not actually relevant then, things happen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).